# Extract all the occuring regex pattern with labels

Tags: python, regex

I have following code return to extract all the patterns from regex and store it

How do i get expected ouutput, Here problem i am facing is there are 2 email id in my text but it shows only one why is this happeneing how do I correct this? also 21 is in date format but that is counted as NUMSTR instead of 123456 as NUMSTR how do i correct this mistake . I guess it is just taking 1st occurence  how do i get all occurences if it occurs in text?

```
import re
def replace_entities(example):
    res = ''
    # dd mm yyyy
    m = re.search("(\d{1,31}(:? |\-|\/)\d{1,12}(:? |\-|\/)\d{4})", example)  # dd/mm/yyyy
    if m:
        res = res + "\n{} : DATESTR".format(m.group())
    # email id
    m = re.search("[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+", example)
    if m:
        res = res +"\n{} : EMAILIDSTR".format(m.group())
    # URL
    m = re.search('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', example)
    if m:

        res= res +"\n{} : URLSTR".format(m.group())
    # NUMBERS
    m = re.search(r'\d+', example)
    if m:
        res = res + "\n{} : NUMSTR".format(m.group())
    return res.strip()

print(replace_entities('My name is ali, Date is 21/08/2018 Total amount is chandanpatil@yahoo.com euros 10,2018/13/09  saylijawale@gmail.com. https://imarticus.com   Account number is 123456'))
```

Following is output i get:

```
21/08/2018 : DATESTR
chandanpatil@yahoo.com : EMAILIDSTR
https://imarticus.com : URLSTR
21 : NUMSTR   # this is not correct
```

Expected output is

```
21/08/2018 : DATESTR
chandanpatil@yahoo.com : EMAILIDSTR
saylijawale@gmail.com : EMAILIDSTR
https://imarticus.com : URLSTR
123456 :NUMSTR
```

Comment: You are more likely to get responses if you give a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question.

Comment: @Alex  can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: If you give a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question, I'll take a look.

Comment: @Alex  I have  Minimized  my code and have shared what problem is facing , you can take a look now. Thank you

Comment: First off I'd suggest using different variables for each re.search() assignment, as that's part of the reason why you're getting '21 : NUMSTR'. Second off, you have overlapping regex conditions in your number and date parsing so unless you split the string and iterate over it or remove matches as you find them your NUMSTR regex will pick up the same digits found in the previous date matches.

Comment: @zyd can you help with some small example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to get all email-ids and iterate over each.

For `NUMSTR`, it seems your code finds the first number in `example`. Instead of that if your input format is the same, get the last number of the string.

```
import re

def replace_entities(example):
    res = ''

    # dd mm yyyy
    m = re.search("(\d{1,31}(:? |\-|\/)\d{1,12}(:? |\-|\/)\d{4})", example)  # dd/mm/yyyy
    if m:
        res = res + "\n{} : DATESTR".format(m.group())

    # email id
    m = re.findall("[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+", example)
    if m:
        for id in m:
            res = res +"\n{} : EMAILIDSTR".format(id)

    # URL
    m = re.search('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', example)
    if m:
        res= res +"\n{} : URLSTR".format(m.group())

    # NUMBERS
    s = r'{}'.format(example)
    m = re.match('.*?([0-9]+)$', s)
    if m:
        res = res + "\n{} : NUMSTR".format(m.group(1))
    return res.strip()

print(replace_entities('My name is ali, Date is 21/08/2018 Total amount is chandanpatil@yahoo.com euros 10,2018/13/09  saylijawale@gmail.com. https://imarticus.com   Account number is 123456'))

'''
21/08/2018 : DATESTR
chandanpatil@yahoo.com : EMAILIDSTR 
saylijawale@gmail.com : EMAILIDSTR
https://imarticus.com : URLSTR           
123456 : NUMSTR 
 '''
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write yourself a small generator function with alternatives in the regular expression:

```
import re

data = """My name is ali, Date is 21/08/2018 Total amount is chandanpatil@yahoo.com euros 10,2018/13/09  saylijawale@gmail.com. https://imarticus.com   Account number is 123456"""

def finder(string=None):
    # define the tokens
    tokens = {
        'DATESTR': r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', 
        'EMAILIDSTR': r'\S+@\S+',
        'URLSTR': r'https?://\S+',
        'NUMSTR': r'\d+'}

    # build the expression
    # using join and a listcomp
    rx = re.compile("|".join(
        ['(?P<{}>{})'.format(key, value) 
        for key, value in tokens.items()])
    )

    # loop over the found matches
    for match in rx.finditer(string):
        for token in tokens:
            value = match.group(token)
            if value:
                if token in ['DATESTR', 'EMAILIDSTR']:
                    value = value.rstrip('.')
                yield (value, token)
                break

# iterate over the found tokens
for value, token in finder(data):
    print("Value: {}, Token: {}".format(value, token))
```

Yielding

```
Value: 21/08/2018, Token: DATESTR
Value: chandanpatil@yahoo.com, Token: EMAILIDSTR
Value: 10, Token: NUMSTR
Value: 2018, Token: NUMSTR
Value: 13, Token: NUMSTR
Value: 09, Token: NUMSTR
Value: saylijawale@gmail.com, Token: EMAILIDSTR
Value: https://imarticus.com, Token: URLSTR
Value: 123456, Token: NUMSTR
```

---

See [**a demo for the expression on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/9prPiH/1).